# iOS: How to fade in image background and text of a label?

Tags: ios

I've seen similar questions asked before but the solutions I tried not working very well.

Here is part of the code. First, a label is defined.

```
UILabel* _label;

...
```

Below is the animation code inside touchesBegan of the label. So basically, when the label is clicked, I would like to gradually fade in background image and change the text color.

```
_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"];
CGSize imageSize = _label.frame.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
                     _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
                     _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(highlightEnded:finished:context:)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"stoped");
                 }];
```

The image background and text color change correctly, but no animation; both of them changes rapidly.

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: do you want a transparent effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` instead of `animateWithDuration:` when animating text.

Comment: I tried transitionWithView on animating text, it still changed rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

After trying half a dozen or so suggestions, I found one way that guarantees to work is to add an extra UIImageView as the background (set the background color of label as clearColor), then animate through its alpha. This is as good as I can solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate text color changes or background image changes.
What you can do is

```
image1.alpha = 0; 
image2.alpha = 1; 

[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
       image1.alpha = 1; 
       image2.alpha = 0;
}];
```

This would give you a fade effect.
You could manually insert image1 and image2 as subViews of the label.

Answer (score -1):

```
CATransition *animation = CATransition.animation;
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

[viewToFade.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fade"];
```

Should work with both image views and labels.